# Tradingview Technical Indicators Chart library not showing complete historical data

Tags: tradingview-api

I'm using Tradingview Technical Analysis Chart library with a UDF adapter for connecting my data. The data provider is my own API. I want to draw candlestick chart using historical data. The trading data is 5 minutes OHLC price candle along with volume. Trading hours are from 9:15 to 15:25 +5:30 time. The problem is that often the chart won't display the correct beginning time of the day, but it always end at 15:25. For example, some random date it will start from 9:45 or 10:30 or any other time and ends at 15:25. It doesn't skip any data point in between. Checking the server log shows that the GET request doesn't start from 9:15. Refreshing the chart changes the beginning time, need not correctly. Anyone familiar with this library, kindly help.

Checked the logs and observed that the library is making incorrect GET requests. The number of bars requested are provided correctly by the server. Went through documentation, but couldn't find any solution. Have also posted this on Github (https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/issues/7801)